# What is the advantage that wrapping the Request from web browser to server in an object

Tags: .net

I read in the 70-515 Book that, By wrapping the HTTP request in a programmable object, ASP.NET provides your code access
to things such as the cookies associated with your site, the query string parameters passed with
the URL, and the path to the requested resource, and allows you to work with other relevant
request-based information.

But how it is possible by wrapping into an object gives you access to cookies etc.. 
Can any one please explain....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No amount of wrapping code into an object will give you access to things you did not have access to before.

It would be more accurate to say that it gives you *convenient* access to things by presenting you with a nice simple interface and taking care of the manual work (working directly with more primitive values like HTTP headers) so that you can work at a higher level of abstraction.

Answer (score 0):

Because of the `HttpRequest` class, you can use the `Request.Cookies` property.

Answer (score 0):

Means that instead of parsing the HTTP headers and payloads manually, it does that for you and puts it in the object:

```
 HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies
```

I am not encouraging you to use `HttpContext.Current` by the way.

Answer (score 0):

In the section you mentioned, Request object is being discussed, so taking just one line out of context may lead to misinterpretation. See below.

Page 7 of Chapter 1 states that

> The communication from the web browser to the web server is referred
>   to as a request. In ASP.NET, there is a Request object that is used to
>   represent the web browser’s communications to the web server. ASP.NET
>   wraps the resource request in an object that can be queried in code.
>   **By wrapping the HTTP request in a programmable object, ASP.NET
>   provides your code access to things such as the cookies associated
>   with your site, the query string parameters passed with the URL, and
>   the path to the requested resource**, and allows you to work with other
>   relevant request-based information.